# Pivot query genetrating duplicate rows with null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

My pivot query is generating duplicate rows, and i'm blocked. can anyone solve this?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[test2]
AS
    BEGIN

        --Declare necessary variables
        DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
        DECLARE @WeekColumns AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

--Get unique values of pivot column  
        SELECT  @WeekColumns = COALESCE(@WeekColumns + ',', '')
                + QUOTENAME(name)
        FROM    ( SELECT    name
                  FROM      ( SELECT    [id_week]
                                      , name
                                      , value
                                      , prjfamilyID
                                      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY name 
                                                            ORDER BY [id_week] ASC ) rn
                              FROM      weekvalues
                            ) a
                  WHERE     rn = 1
                ) AS PivotExample;

        SELECT  @WeekColumns;

--Create the dynamic query with all the values for 
--pivot column at runtime
        SET @SQLQuery = N'SELECT  prjfamilyID, ' + @WeekColumns + '
    FROM [dbo].[weekvalues] 
    PIVOT( MAX(value) 
          FOR name IN (' + @WeekColumns + ')) AS P';

        SELECT  @SQLQuery;
--Execute dynamic query
        EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery;

    END;
```

and Here is the result i am getting

```
1   NULL    NULL    1004    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
1   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    997     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
1   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    992     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
1   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    997
2   NULL    NULL    2100    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2036    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2014    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2040
3   NULL    NULL    1944    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
3   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1914    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
3   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1882    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
3   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1880
```

what i want is for number 1 for example i want to combine all rows in one containing all values

thanks

Comment: Post sample data, query looks right to me. Generally this problem will come only when you have unwanted column selected in pivot source query but in your case it is not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you change your `@SQLQuery` query with this one and try again?

```
SET @SQLQuery = 
        N'SELECT * FROM (SELECT prjfamilyID, value, name
    FROM [dbo].[weekvalues] ) SRC
    PIVOT( MAX(value) 
          FOR name IN (' + @WeekColumns + ')) AS P';
```

Comment: Hello Sarslan,
can you please explain what was the issue because i have the same probleme with a other stored proc
thanks

Comment: The problem is you were using all column of weekvalues table. that's why pivot put all columns combination except value and name as an output. I just select and use only necessary columns with using subquery. if you put pivot  to table directly it use all columns.